# "import" in Visual Studio Code is showing "invalid syntax" error

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code

I am starting out learning Python and I am playing around with Visual Studio Code. I copied some code that I had used in Jupier notebooks and when I try to run it it gives me an error at the "from" and "import portion".

[image: Description]

Am I missing something? I made sure to install the Python extension within Visual Studio Code.

Comment: `from` and `import` have to be on the same line (unless the line ends with a `\ `)

Comment: `from foo import bar` has to appear on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstanding the `from` and `import`. `import` means import the whole package. `from` must be used with `import`, it means import something inside the package.

Your code must be like below:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
```

It means that import the `BlockBlobService` from the package `azure.storage.blob`.